# I would like to know if Spatialite is considered as a NoSQL database?

Tags: nosql, spatialite

I would like to know if Spatialite is considered as a NoSQL database.

> What is NoSQL?
>
> NoSQL encompasses a wide variety of different database technologies
>   and were developed in response to a rise in the volume of data stored
>   about users, objects and products, the frequency in which this data is
>   accessed, and performance and processing needs. Relational databases,
>   on the other hand, were not designed to cope with the scale and
>   agility challenges that face modern applications, nor were they built
>   to take advantage of the cheap storage and processing power available
>   today.
>
> NoSQL Database Types
>
> Document databases pair each key with a complex data structure known
>   as a document. Documents can contain many different key-value pairs,
>   or key-array pairs, or even nested documents.
>
> Graph stores are used to store information about networks, such as
>   social connections. Graph stores include Neo4J and HyperGraphDB.
>
> Key-value stores are the simplest NoSQL databases. Every single item
>   in the database is stored as an attribute name (or "key"), together
>   with its value. Examples of key-value stores are Riak and Voldemort.
>   Some key-value stores, such as Redis, allow each value to have a type,
>   such as "integer", which adds functionality.
>
> Wide-column stores such as Cassandra and HBase are optimized for
>   queries over large datasets, and store columns of data together,
>   instead of rows.
>
> The Benefits of NoSQL
>
> When compared to relational databases, NoSQL databases are more
>   scalable and provide superior performance, and their data model
>   addresses several issues that the relational model is not designed to
>   address:
>
> Large volumes of structured, semi-structured, and unstructured data
>   Agile sprints, quick iteration, and frequent code pushes
>   Object-oriented programming that is easy to use and flexible
>   Efficient, scale-out architecture instead of expensive, monolithic
>   architecture

Explanation is from [MongoDB site](http://www.mongodb.com/learn/nosql)

Comment: Why does it matter to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NoSQL is a very vaguely defined term (I once wrote [a blog post about this issue](http://ontraindevelopment.blogspot.de/2013/07/there-is-no-such-thing-as-nosql.html)).

But even though the definition of NoSQL is quite fuzzy, you can definitely say that SpatiaLite is not a NoSQL database. It is, in fact, not a database at all. It is just a library for using SQLite (which is a SQL database).

The library includes some utility-functions which make it easier to store and query geospatial data in SQLite. But that data is still queried with normal SQL syntax and stored in a relational manner, so you couldn't even claim that it is a NoSQL abstraction layer on a SQL database.